# elasticsearch with istio proxy disconnect from each other

Tags: elasticsearch, istio

I'm trying to install elasticsearch from Helm on namespace with istio auto inject sidecar.

When installing it with no sidecar all is working well but with sidecar I see the servers disconnect from each other and I don't know how to debug it. (no virtual service and no gateway only internal communication from elastic-0 to elastic-1)

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: logs from where? elasticsearch? as i see elasticsearch just see node left and node join and from envoy i see a lot of updates info

Comment: I also have this error with Istio 1.0.5 and mTLS enabled. Envoy just has watchFileEvents from the cert filewatcher in its logs, elasticsearch has exceptions that the internal transport is corrupted: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (15,3,1,0)

Comment: When using Istio mTLS, the ES readiness probes have to be changed from http to exec wget since Kubelet is not part of the mesh and doesn't have the Istio certs.

Comment: Here is an example of a readiness probe when using mTLS https://github.com/stefanprodan/flagger/blob/master/charts/flagger/templates/deployment.yaml#L54

Comment: in my case we are not using mtls and the pods not killed its running just i see disconnects in the elasticsearch logs

Comment: @geNAZt how did you resolve that error?